# Does changing web.config deletes all cache objects?

Tags: asp.net

If i change the web.config file , does my application delets all cache objects ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you change the web.config file, your application pool resets. This will clear out any in-memory caches that exist in the process space of the application pool.

If you cache items on the disk or in a database (or other shared resource not in the same memory space as you application), the cache will not be cleared.

Comment: so can i use this approach to clear cache so that the latest content get loaded for the users without any hard reload on the browser?

Comment: How would a server side cache change cause an update in the browser?

Comment: i am not sure, but making a change say adding a space in the web config forces the browser to hard reload, i made this happen by hosting a angular website with server side rendering in IIS

Comment: @Oded I think web.config change resets App Domain, not App Pool.

Answer (score 0):

Web.config change will reset App Domain - so all in-memory cached objects and session items will be cleared.